# Filter Table, based on field in another table

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I'm stumped with this. I have a table with various fields:
`$employees`. This, I guess, is what you call a collection, I think, that when I call, returns all employee records in the database (4 records in this example)

Each employee record has the following fields
`first_name`, `last_name`, `age`, `other_id`

There is another table (or collection), which I'm calling filter table. It is called `$other_ids`. This has two records, with the following fields - `id`, `id_name`.

I want to be able to filter the `$employees` table so that it only keeps the records, where `other_id` is equal to one of the two values of `id` in the filter table- `$other_ids`

So for example, if the filter table has the following two records:

```
[{"id":1 "id_name":"one"}, {"id":2, "id_name":"two"}]
```

And the $employee table contains the records:

```
[{"first_name":"ted", "surname_name":"stark", "age":35, "other_id":1},
{"first_name":"fred", "surname_name":"strange", "age":30, "other_id":2},
{"first_name":"incredible", "surname_name":"hulk", "age":25, "other_id":3},
{"first_name":"captain", "surname_name":"stone", "age":28, "other_id":2}]
```

After, the filtering, it should return `$employees_filtered` should only have records **1, 2, and 4**

I've tried doing `left-join` and using `whereHas`, and where clauses, but nothing works!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like -

```
$otherId = [1, 2];
$employees_filtered = Employee::with('Others')->whereIn('other_id', $otherId)->get();
```

Please don't forget to make a relationship with their model.
In `Other.php` model -

```
public function Employees()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Other', 'other_id', 'id');
}
```

And in `Employee.php` model -

```
public function Others()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Employee', 'other_id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The relationships in the model were already set up. The wherein function worked like a charm!